# click href by class

Tags: vb.net

I have code to click the first href of class:

```
For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a") 
    If Element.OuterHtml.Contains("showFileOptions") Then 
        Element.InvokeMember("click") 
        Exit For 
    End If 
Next Element
```

How can I click next href of this class ?

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the `Exit For` line from your code.

Comment: no,i need click showFileOptions after click this click editFileBtn edit textbox click button and click next showfileoptions